# Dealing with spaces in header names

Tags: r

I want to cut up a `.csv` file and reformat using R

Firstly, I have spaces in my column header names ie `"Hello Joe"` and if my file is `DATA`, I'm not sure how to deal with the file name spaces. They need to have spaces its a the way my system has been built.

R does like when I write: `DATA$Hello Joe`
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: if you want to leave the spaces in there put backticks around the name of the column `data$\`Hello Joe\``

Comment: But when you read in those files, the headers usually get changed to `Hello.Joe`. Verify the correct names with `names(DATA)`

Answer (score 0):

To reference with `$` you need to put backticks around the column names with spaces, e.g.

```
data$`Hello Joe`
```

Otherwise, if you find it easier to work without spaces you could temporarily put in an underscore and replace that with a space again later

```
df
  Hello Joe Hi Joe
1         1      2

> colnames(df) = gsub(" ", "_",colnames(df))
> df
  Hello_Joe Hi_Joe
1         1      2

> colnames(df) = gsub("_", " ",colnames(df))
> df
  Hello Joe Hi Joe
1         1      2
```